# Android Bundle Comparison with String

Tags: java, android, if-statement, bundle

The 'if' controls never work when I get datas from bundle, please help me.. I need comparison for bundle's data in 'if' block because I have to change textview according to data.

```
result = getIntent().getExtras();
String get = result.getString("secilen");

if(number == 0) {
    imgView.setImageResource( R.drawable.tas );

    //txtV.setText(get);

    if (get == "A"){ // if even "A" come never read if block
        txtV.setText("...");
    }

    if (get == "B"){
        txtV.setText("...");
    }

    if (get == "C") {
        txtV.setText("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is DataType of number in your cide? Is it int?

Answer (score 2):

use **equals** instead of **==** for compare strings  as:

```
if (get.equals("A")){ 
    txtV.setText("...");
}

if (get.equals("B")){
    txtV.setText("...");
}

if (get.equals("C")) {
    txtV.setText("...");
}
```

Comment: oh! thank you, why i do not try this approach, interesting.. thank you again

Comment: String type in Java is immutable thats why == is not the same as equals

Comment: @rallat : you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus for why we not use "==" for comparing strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if (get.equals("A")) { //my code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings via `==`, because that will only check for object identity, while two strings with the same content (e.g. `A`) might be separate objects. Use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead:

```
if ("A".equals(get)) {
        txtV.setText("...");
}
```

Note the different order in the comparison. That prevents `NullPointerExceptions` if `get` should be null.

[Here is a good explanation for this.](http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/#.UAVnJpHEKPM)

Comment: If one guy already provided the exact answers then why you guyz are repeating the same answer again and again. Bad one

Comment: @Kabir121 Because I didn't provide the same answer. I provided more information and used a different approach which makes for better code. Also, the other answers were sent while I was already writing mine.

Answer (score -1):

```
result = getIntent().getExtras();
if(result!=null){
    String get = result.getString("secilen");
    if(number == 0){
    imgView.setImageResource( R.drawable.tas );


    if (get.equals("A"))
        txtV.setText("...");
    }

    else if (get.equals("B")){
        txtV.setText("...");
    }

    else if (get.equals("C")) {
        txtV.setText("...");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If one guy already provided the exact answers then why you guyz are repeating the same answer again and again. Bad one

Comment: @Kabir121 i think you are lacking in android..cant u see i have added if(result!=null) condition which you wont see in any code above.by not adding this might give null pointer exception if value is null..